# Install caffe2 in Google Colaboratory with GPU support

Tags: google-colaboratory, caffe2

Is it possible to install caffe2 (not caffe) in Google Colaboratory with GPU support?
I tried in many ways, following [installation instructions](https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=ubuntu&configuration=compile) from Caffe2, but I couldn't succeed to install with GPU support.
When I test caffe2 installation, I get message:
"This caffe2 python run does not have GPU support. Will run in CPU only mode."